# Modify XDocument based on a replace rule

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML document that looks like this

```
<root>
  <Product>
    <ProductName attr1="asdf">
      <Feature1 attr1="asdf">
        <Feature2 />
      </Feature1>
      <Feature3 attr1="asdf" attr2="qwer" />
    </ProductName>
  </Product>
</root>
```

And I need to update it based on commands in form of XML, like those

```
<XmlCommands>
  <AddProduct>
    <Product>
      ...
    </Product>
  </AddProduct>
  <AddFeature>
    <Feature product="ProductName" mode="Add">
      <Feature4 attr1="zxcv"/>
    </Feature>
    <Feature product="ProductName" path="???" mode="Replace">
      ???
    </Feature>
  </AddFeature>
</XmlCommands>
```

So basically, there are different type of commands

`<AddProduct>` takes the content of the `<AddProduct>` element and add it to the `<root>` element
`<AddFeature>` with `mode="Add"` takes the content of the `<Feature>` element and adds it to the `<ProductName>` tag according to the `product` attribute

Where it gets tricky is with the `<AddFeature>` with `mode="Replace"`. I need to find a way to take the content of the `<Feature>` element and use it to replace the content of an element or of an attribute, potentially based on a `path` attribute in the `<Feature>` element

Any idea or suggestions? Would there be a way of finding an XElement in an XDocument based on a path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about XPath? It is kind of path expression enriched with filtering ability, so that we can match any specific part of an XML document not only based on the element's path but also element's value, element's attribute value, and so on.

For example, you can pass following XPath to replace existing `<ProductName>` having attribute `attr1` equals `"asdf"` :

```
<Feature product="ProductName" mode="Replace"
         path="//Product/ProductName[@attr1='asdf']">
  .....
</Feature>
```

We can use [`XPathSelectElement()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351355%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method to get specific `XElement` from `XDocument` using XPath expression as argument. Simply pass the `path` attribute value to this method and it will do the job of finding the correct element.

For references :

- [MSDN: XPath Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [w3schools XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)
- [W3C : XML Path Language (XPath)
  Version 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)

Comment: What do I need to reference/use to be able to use XPathSelectElement() ?

Comment: `using System.Xml.XPath;`, refer to MSDN link in this answer, the namespace and assembly information are there.

Comment: If I use the `XPathSelectElement()` with the path you had in the example, will that select the `<Feature>` node or the `@attr1` attribute ?

Comment: It will select `<ProductName>`, the node mentioned as last part of the path (what between `[]` are only filters for corresponding node)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the environment this transformation was to occur: inline processing of the XML? ETL? ??

You can develop an XML transform template (XMLT) (conditional to the `<AddFearture mode=OPTION>`) to add new Elements/Attribute to the Feature in-place. This template coudl be applied inline. There are a lot of examples on how to do this on the web - Google is your friend!

You could also write an app to open and manipulate the XML Tree using some framework library like .Net's Linq or System.XML. Arguably easier, but requires external processing.

HTH!